# How do I tell angular to set default value for drop down when no match is found in model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have the following select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selSigningAuthorityDisplayName"
        ng-model="selectedUser.SigningAuthority"
        ng-options="signingAuthority as signingAuthority.SigningAuthorityDisplayName for signingAuthority in signingAuthorityList track by signingAuthority.SigningAuthoritySystemName">
</select>
```

This works perfectly when I'm editing an existing user profile and the `selectedUser.SigningAuthority` object is populated. The drop down defaults to the value of `SigningAuthority` as expected. But when I try to add a new user profile and `selectedUser.SigingingAuthority` is `null` I want the drop down list to default to a specific value. How do I tell angular to select a specific default value when `selectedUser.SigningAuthority` is null?

Comment: Set `SigningAuthority` to the default value when you first create `selectedUser`. Your code should be setting up your model for your UI to react to, not the other way around.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. There's no error thrown, but setting selectedUser.SigningAuthority.SigningAuthoritySystemName = "SME", which is the default value I want isn't reflected in the drop down. The drop down just defaults to a blank selection, forcing the user to manually select an option.

Comment: Read the answer you got. It explains how to do it. The selectedUser.SigningAuthority object must be one of the objects in the array of selectable options.

Answer (score 1):

Add default option to select tag, it's identical as `ng-model=null`

```
<select class="form-control" id="selSigningAuthorityDisplayName" ng-model="selectedUser.SigningAuthority" ng-options="signingAuthority as signingAuthority.SigningAuthorityDisplayName for signingAuthority in signingAuthorityList track by signingAuthority.SigningAuthoritySystemName">
     <option value="">Not selected</option>
</select>
```

Or you can assign value to ng-model inside controller;

```
$scope.selectedUser = {};
$scope.selectedUser.SigningAuthority = $scope.selectedUser.SigningAuthority || $scope.signingAuthorityList[0]; 
//or whatever index; But note, your specific value must be inside this list
```

Comment: @JBNizet updated my answer, if it still doesn't solve, please tell me, i will remove it

Comment: I'm not trying to set a default "Please select" type value, I want it to default to a specific valid selection.